# Join query in Cakephp missing results

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm having troubles with a Cakephp join query. My database is built this way : Contact belongsTo User

In my contact Controller, I have a  fucntioin that search Contacts. Contacts can be searched by User.first_name or User.last_name.

I built my query like this :

```
$options['contain'] = array(
    'User' => array(
        'fields' => array('id', 'first_name', 'last_name'),
    )
);

$options['conditions']['OR'] = array(
    array('Contact.id LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
    array('User.first_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
    array('User.last_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
    array('Building.title LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
    array('City.name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
    array('Manager.first_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
    array('Manager.last_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'),
);

$contacts = $this->Contact->find('all', $options);
```

This query give me that sql query :

```
'SELECT `Contact`.`id`, `Contact`.`specific_works`, `Contact`.`user_id`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, FROM `pfre`.`contacts` AS `Contact` LEFT JOIN `pfre`.`authake_users` AS `User` ON (`Contact`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `Contact`.`white_label_id` = 18 AND ((`Contact`.`id` LIKE '%search%') OR (`User`.`first_name` LIKE '%search%') OR (`User`.`last_name` LIKE '%search%') OR (`Building`.`title` LIKE '%search%') OR (`City`.`name` LIKE '%search%') OR (`Manager`.`first_name` LIKE '%search%') OR (`Manager`.`last_name` LIKE '%search%'))'
```

This give me no results, whereas I should get 2 results (they are in my database).

Does someone understand what is wrong in this query ?

For information, the complete (not simplified, with all the fields) query :

```
'SELECT `Contact`.`id`, `Contact`.`specific_works`, `Contact`.`comments`, `Contact`.`follow`, `Contact`.`priority`, `Contact`.`code`, `Contact`.`step`, `Contact`.`intervention_type`, `Contact`.`intervention_precision`, `Contact`.`energy_consumption_before`, `Contact`.`energy_consumption_after`, `Contact`.`ghg_emission_before`, `Contact`.`ghg_emission_after`, `Contact`.`diagnosis_date`, `Contact`.`diagnostician`, `Contact`.`heating_details`, `Contact`.`heater_details`, `Contact`.`equipments_details`, `Contact`.`wall_details`, `Contact`.`floor_details`, `Contact`.`ceiling_details`, `Contact`.`loan_received`, `Contact`.`anah_project`, `Contact`.`labor_cost`, `Contact`.`equipment_cost`, `Contact`.`other_cost`, `Contact`.`cite_amount`, `Contact`.`anah_amount`, `Contact`.`cee_amount`, `Contact`.`eco_amount`, `Contact`.`tva_amount`, `Contact`.`anah_ase_amount`, `Contact`.`ptz_acquisition_amount`, `Contact`.`anah_other_amount`, `Contact`.`other_helps`, `Contact`.`other_loans`, `Contact`.`monthly_payments`, `Contact`.`hide_consumptions`, `Contact`.`abandonment_reason`, `Contact`.`abandonment_reason_other`, `Contact`.`project_source`, `Contact`.`project_source_other`, `Contact`.`renovation_type`, `Contact`.`work_col_1`, `Contact`.`work_col_2`, `Contact`.`considered_energy`, `Contact`.`considered_ges`, `Contact`.`custom_1_energy`, `Contact`.`custom_1_ges`, `Contact`.`custom_2_energy`, `Contact`.`custom_2_ges`, `Contact`.`performed_energy`, `Contact`.`performed_ges`, `Contact`.`favorite_scenario1`, `Contact`.`favorite_scenario2`, `Contact`.`favorite_scenario3`, `Contact`.`archived`, `Contact`.`user_id`, `Contact`.`manager_id`, `Contact`.`white_label_id`, `Contact`.`building_id`, `Contact`.`ceie_id`, `Contact`.`created`, `Contact`.`modified`, `Contact`.`rennes`, (energy_consumption_before - energy_consumption_after) AS  `Contact__energy_consumption_prevented`, (ghg_emission_before - ghg_emission_after) AS  `Contact__ghg_emission_prevented`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, `Manager`.`id`, `Manager`.`first_name`, `Manager`.`last_name`, `Manager`.`email`, `Manager`.`phone`, `Building`.`id`, `Building`.`title`, `Building`.`city_id` FROM `pfre`.`contacts` AS `Contact` LEFT JOIN `pfre`.`authake_users` AS `User` ON (`Contact`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `pfre`.`authake_users` AS `Manager` ON (`Contact`.`manager_id` = `Manager`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `pfre`.`buildings` AS `Building` ON (`Contact`.`building_id` = `Building`.`id`) INNER JOIN `pfre`.`cities` AS `City` ON (`Building`.`city_id` = `City`.`id`)  WHERE `Contact`.`white_label_id` = 18 AND ((`Contact`.`id` LIKE '%search%') OR (`User`.`first_name` LIKE '%search%') OR (`User`.`last_name` LIKE '%search%') OR (`Building`.`title` LIKE '%search%') OR (`City`.`name` LIKE '%search%') OR (`Manager`.`first_name` LIKE '%search%') OR (`Manager`.`last_name` LIKE '%search%'))'
```

EDIT : 
I sometimes get some result. It depends on the string I use as 'search', but some of them get me the right results.

Comment: This is not related to cakephp but to the SQL executed, hence the tags are wrong. Your query contains errors. In a quick look there is an extra `,` in this part. There could be more errors `, 'User'.'last_name', FROM 'pfre'.'contacts'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is just because I removed some fields to make the query more readable. Complete query added in topic.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem ! When I'm building my query, I set a join :

```
$options['joins'] = array(
            array(
                'table' => 'cities',
                'alias' => 'City',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => [
                    'Building.city_id = City.id'
                ]
            ),
        );
```

Some of my buildings have no city_id. This parameter don't include buildings with no city_id or which city_id is not corresponding to a City.id.

I need now to know how to include results with no city_id.

Thank to all who helped me get a solution !